# URL Rewriting the Chatter Feed

Tags: chatter, force.com-sites, community, urlrewriter

I was going through the notes about [URL Rewriting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm) for a Visualforce based Community, and noticed that while my custom Visualforce Pages mapped correctly, the chatter feed component does not seem to allow hooks for something similar. The example here is if I implement a custom VF page with the [<chatter:feed>](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chatter_feed.htm) component on the VF page, and then update some Accounts to show up in my feed, if I click on the Account link in the feed the default page will show up (/001XXXXXXXXXX), and I don't get an opportunity to redirect that link to a page that is styled appropriately (like /CustomAccount?id=001XXXXXXXXX). I put some debug statements in my URL Rewriter and verified it doesn't even get invoked - I'm suspecting it might have something to do with the Chatter Feed being rendered via Javascript or something similar.

Is the only workaround here (to use that component) creating new Visualforce pages to represent the View action of these objects and somehow determine whether it is being loaded in a Community or not? I'd prefer not to get invasive with the internal Salesforce org, and at that point I'd just succumb to implementing the Chatter Feed manually.

Interestingly, the [chatteranswers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chatteranswers_feeds.htm) components have an attribute for **useUrlRewriter**, but no other components do.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully been able to use javascript/jquery to modify the links in the feed. This method was recommended and implemented by consultants from Salesforce.

Comment: Can you provide some example code demonstrating this approach?

Comment: please provide some code for answering the question properly

Comment: I also explored this route by basically finding all the possible links in the Chatter Feed (User objects + all the Objects available to the Community users), and then writing "onclick" handlers to change the target URL when redirecting. It works as long as you don't forget anything, but seems very hacky.